# Display Row Number with Blazor Virtualize Component

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am using the [Blazor virtualize component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/virtualization?view=aspnetcore-5.0) with asp.net core 5.x to display a grid of data. I want to display the row number. I am not sure if this component supports this functionality.

```
Item Name  
1    Fred  
2    Bob  
3    Craig
```

I tried adding a `coutner` variable but this did not work. The variable is alway 0.

```
 <Virtualize Context="donationRequest" ItemsProvider="@LoadRequests">
        <ItemContent>
            @Counter++
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Counter
                </td>
                <td>
                    donationRequest.Name
                </td>
        </ItemContent>
        <Placeholder>
            <p>
                Loading...
            </p>
        </Placeholder>
    </Virtualize>
```